# Syntax error in MySQL WITH ROLLUP query in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, rollup

Any idea why the following query syntax is wrong:

```
SELECT year, sum(profit)
FROM BASEDATA b 
group by year WITH rollup
```

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near.....

MYSQL Version 5.0.77-community-log

Comment: The part about "right syntax to use near" is important, why did you truncate that?

Comment: had some irrelevant where clauses that I took out...its WITH which is causing the problem (gets highlighted in red by MySql workbench)

Comment: All seems ok. Are you sure you selected the correct database?

Comment: Does it highlight that if you use the query you posted here ?

Comment: mind posting the schema of you BASEDATA table?

Comment: yes works without with rollup

Comment: Really looks like an X file! Are you sure that the client (API/etc.) your are using supports it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in MySQL Workbench...the query runs fine under MySQL Query Browser.

Answer (score 1):

Same error, but i found a discussion :
[mysql WITH ROLLUP](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=57178)

if execute the query with ctrl+enter you get error, but if you execute with ctrl+alt+enter
then the query is ok!

Hope the fix this bug...

Comment: Thanks! On Mac it is the same. Cmd+Enter -> Syntax error. Shift+Cmd+Enter -> Works.